# How to find the latest record before a date?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

It's probably easier for me to explain this using sample tables.

So I have two tables, (not sure how to convert this into formatted text)

1. Product EOM Table

[image: Product EOM Table]

2. Transaction Table

[image: Transaction Table]

And the result I want to get is to find out the latest transaction date before each EOM date, like below.

[image: Result Table]

Comment: please avoid posting image, use formatted text instead

Comment: `rank function is not allowed as a join condition` use a derived table or CTE

Comment: Hi Penn, you can use this site https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/ to format your tables to ASCII text tables.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:
I've achieved this using the code below, just wondering if there's any better idea?

```
SELECT 
    PE.[Product ID],
    PE.[EOM Date],
    MAX(TR.[Transaction Date]) AS [Last Transaction Date]
FROM [TD_External_Data].[dbo].[Product EOM] AS PE
LEFT JOIN [TD_External_Data].[dbo].[Transaction] AS TR
    ON PE.[Product ID] = TR.[Product ID]
    AND PE.[EOM Date] >= TR.[Transaction Date]
GROUP BY
    PE.[Product ID],
    PE.[EOM Date]
ORDER BY
    PE.[Product ID],
    PE.[EOM Date]
```

Comment: Please don't update your question to include the answer. Instead, post it as an answer to your own question. Stack Overflow operates off of a strict question and answer format, and it gets confusing when you place the answer in the question.